# What is the correct way to write "subject noun and pronoun will be etc ..." in French?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-disjoint, disjonctif

If I want to say "Julie and I will be in Paris next week." in English, it has to be "I" not "me". On the other hand, "You will see Julie and me in Paris next week.", has to be "me" not "I". Isolating the pronoun, makes it obvious which is correct. "I will be ..." or "You will see me ...".

How does this work in French?

As far as I can tell with my limited knowledge, I have to use "moi" in both cases.

"Julie et moi serons à Paris la semaine prochaine."

"Vous nous verrez Julie et moi à Paris la semaine prochaine."

Is this correct?

Comment: All correct - and that's about the only way to go about that.

Comment: Even if you were to change the order, il would still be "moi": "Moi et Julie serons..."

Comment: Perhaps I could edit the question a little to make it complete for all six persons (1st, 2nd, 3rd, singular and plural), so someone could give a comprehensive answer that I can then accept?

Comment: Geoff merci de suivre le modèle question/réponses de SE, tu as raison : il faut une réponse pour accepter une bonne réponse !  Je plussoie l'effort contre les réponses dans les commentaires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the disjunctive or tonic pronoun is used in this case.  You can also repeat the pronoun as the subject or nominative when it is plural.  Still it is a subject pronoun clearly in the singular like in English, *Je serai à Paris la semaine prochaine* **not** **moi serai* or **toi seras*

Examples:
Toi et moi, nous serons à Paris
Toi et moi serons là.
Toi et moi, on sera là (more frequent)

You can say *Moi, je serai à Paris la semaine prochaine.* for emphasis.

Let's assume all these sentences end in "next week," *...la semaine prochaine.*

Toi, tu seras à la fête...

Lui, il sera là

Nous, on sera là

Julie et moi, nous serons à Arles. (*on* is more common)

Who will you see at the party?

Moi, je verrai Jules et Jim.   Je les verrai.
Toi, tu les verras.
Nola et lui, ils jouent bien (Nola et Jim vont faire la queue sans parler.)

Alec et Nola seront à Paris, nous les verrons bientôt.

Nous les verrons, Alec et Nola.

Still put the other person's name or pronom disjoint first, compare :

Nola et lui seront à Paris = Nola et lui, ils seront là = Lui et Nola, ils seront là.

-